# I want to change display of a div when clicked -React Styled Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am creating a div using styled component. I want to change the visibility of the div on button clicked,

```
const Category = () => {
  const [showCategory, setShowCategory] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    setShowCategory(false)
  }, [])
  return (
<button onClick={() => {  setShowCategory(true)}}>
   New Category
</button>
        <AdminInputStyle>
          <form>
            <form-group>
              <label>Add Category</label>
              <input type='text' />
            </form-group>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </form>
        </AdminInputStyle>

  )

}
```

Here's the styled component

```
const AdminInputStyle = styled.div`
  display: ${(d) => (d.showCategory ? 'show' : 'hidden')};
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example, but in the case we will use a Button. Clicking it will alter the visibility.

1. You must pass a property to the styled component if you want it to be visible based on that prop. In your example, you don't pass a prop to the styled component in this scenario, which is why the component cannot detect if it should be visible or not.
2. You will need to / can use the `css` function from the `styled-components` library. This can help you return styles based on the properties your styled-component will have. In this example, our property that we pass to the button will be called `visible`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components/macro';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;

    ${({ visible }) => {
        return css`
            visibility: ${visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'};
        `;
    }}
`;

export default function Button({ children, visible, onClick }) {
    return (
        <StyledButton visible={visible} onClick={onClick}>
            {children}
        </StyledButton>
    );
}

Button.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    visible: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
};
```

You can see that passing the `visible` prop will enable the button to alter its' styles based on whether that property is true or false. We utilize a function within the component that returns the css function and this will control the `visibility` css property.

Here is how we utilize the button and pass props to it from another component; in this example just the App.js file:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/Button';

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  function handleClick() {
    setVisible(!visible);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button visible={visible} onClick={handleClick}>
        Click
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FYI: For the css; you don't want `display: hidden;`. `hidden` is an invalid value for the display prop. You'd want `display: none;` if you don't want the element to be in the DOM. `visibility: hidden;` will add the element to the DOM, but it won't be visible. You can use whichever works best for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this too, show when you need to show the add category when you press add category

```
return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowCategory(true);
        }}
      >
        New Category
      </button>
      {showCategory && (
        <AdminInputStyle>
          <form>
            <form-group>
              <label>Add Category</label>
              <input type="text" />
            </form-group>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </form>
        </AdminInputStyle>
      )}
    </>
  );
```